# Speed of convergence of $\frac1n\int_0^1 f(x/n)dx\to0$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^2(0,1)$, this implies that
$$\frac1n\left|\int_0^1 f(x/n) dx\,\right| =\left|\int_0^{1/n} f(x) dx\,\right|=\left|\langle \chi_{[0,1/n]}, f\rangle_{L^2}\right|≤\|\chi_{[0,1/n]}\|_{L^2}\cdot \|f\|_{L_2}=\frac{\|f\|_{L^2}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

My question is whether there is a better bound on the speed of convergence than a $\frac1{\sqrt n}$ factor.

I ask because playing around with different $f$ it looks like
$$\sum_n \frac1{n^2}\left|\int_0^1 f(x/n) dx\,\right|^2$$
is always summable, and I would like to find a bound like $\sum_n\frac1{n^2}\left|\int_0^1 f(x/n)\, dx\right|^2≤M\|f\|_{L^2}^2$.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 f(x/n)\,dx = n\int_0^{1/n} f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: From your first line, you seem to have assumed $f \in L^1(0,1/n)$...

Comment: @DanielFischer I was actually looking at $\frac1n \int_0^1f(x/n) dx$, I fixed the question

Comment: Okay. For $f\in L^p$ with $p > 2$, you get a better bound via Hölder. Since for a constant $f$ you get exactly $\frac{c}{n}$, and that's what Hölder gives you with $p = \infty$, it doesn't seem unreasonable that one can't get a better exponent than $n^{-1/2}$. Try with something like $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\cdot \lvert \log x\rvert^{\alpha}},$$ $\alpha > 1/2$ to see what you get from that.

Comment: @DanielFischer do you mean to include the $\frac1{\log(x)^\alpha}$ type singularity at $x=1$? Because it looks like that kind of a term is not in $L^2$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa This should follow from $f\in L^2(0,1)$ though, right?

Comment: @s.harp No, I just wasn't attentive and forgot to exclude the singularity at $1$. The point is the behaviour at $0$, and the logarithm makes it quadratically integrable there, but keeps it out of $L^p,\, p > 2$. Cut the function off at $x = 1/2$ or so, where exactly doesn't matter since we're interested in large $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This argument owes a large debt to the comments of Daniel Fischer and D. Thomine!*

I think the following argument works. I'll assume $f$ is real-valued to avoid a lot of conjugation signs.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\bigg(\int_0^1 f(x/n) \,dx\,\bigg)^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\int_0^{1/n} f(x) \,dx\bigg)^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{1/n} \int_0^{1/n} f(x) f(y) \,dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x) f(y) \bigg( \sum_{\substack{n\ge 1 \\ 1/n \ge x \\ 1/n \ge y}} 1 \bigg) \,dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x) f(y) \min\{\lfloor 1/x \rfloor,\lfloor 1/y \rfloor\} \,dx\,dy \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x) f(y) \lfloor 1/y \rfloor \,dx\,dy \\
&\le 2 \int_0^1 f(y) \frac1y \int_0^y f(x) \,dx\,dy \\
&=2 \int_0^1 f(y) g(y) \,dy,
\end{align*}
where we have defined $g(y) = \frac1y \int_0^y f(x) \,dx$. [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) tells us that $g$ is square-integrable and $\|g\|_2 \le 2\|f\|_2$. Therefore by Cauchy–Schwarz,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\bigg(\int_0^1 f(x/n) \,dx\,\bigg)^2 &\le 2 \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 \le 4\|f\|_2^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: That needs to be $2\lVert f\rVert_2^2$ at the end. Since the left hand side scales quadratically, the right hand side can't scale linearly.

Comment: I don't see why $$\int_0^1 f(y)\frac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(x)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1 f(y)\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\,dy$$ should hold. I see the first is equal to $$\int_0^1 f(y) \int_0^1 f(yz)\,dz\,dy.$$

Comment: Good catch, @DanielFischer. I'm trying a different approach after that point. It's currently not working out, but I did a wasteful step in the second-to-last display; maybe there's a way to recover.

Comment: Use Hardy's inequality to show that $\frac{1}{y} \int_0^y f(t)dt$ is square integrable, then Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: What @D.Thomine suggested kills it quickest, I think.