# Equivalence to absolutely summable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

For a sequence $x_n$ (in $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ or some Banach space, its all the same), is $n x_n\to0$ equivalent to
$$\sum_n \|x_n\|$$
being absolutely summable?

---

I'm sure the result is standard, but I don't know what to search for to find it.

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983026/speed-of-convergence-of-frac1n-int-01-fx-ndx-to0) where I was looking for a better bound than $1/n$ for the speed of convergence of some expression. Square summability was shown to hold. If the statement here is false, then there is a family of better bounds.

Comment: Good question. In a Banach space the absolutely summability is equivalent to summability, so you're asking if the convergence of $\sum_nx_n$ is equivalent to $nx_n\to0$. This kind of results are known as _tauberian results_, It might help you to make a quick search online.

Comment: @mathbeing thank you for the hint, but searching around _tauberian results_ appear to refer to classifications of whether one method of defining an infinite sum is contained in another. I think my question here is far more elementary. I'm not sure how a classification would help decide whether the series converges or not.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the only way of proving or disproving your claim is through tauberian results. I wrote that comment so you have in mind that it might be a difficult question. In fact, if you pay attention to those tauberian results usually one find two methods of summing and put conditions to imply the convergence of each one in terms of the other. In complex analysis the condition $na_n\to0$ is the needed hypothesis to guarantee that _Abel summability_ implies _usual summability_. This suggest that the summability of $x_n$ might be a stronger statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that $\sum_{n>4}\frac{1}{n\log (n)}$ diverges (*). So no.

(*) you can show that, if $a_n>0 $ is not increasing, then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ does (**). If you apply this to $\sum_{n>4}\frac{1}{n\log (n)}$ you'll see it diverges.

(**) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests, Cauchy condensation test.

(The implication $\sum |a_n|<\infty  \Rightarrow n|a_n| \rightarrow 0 $ does hold and is not difficult to prove, at least if $|a|_n$ is not increasing).

Comment: Do you know of a sequence $a_n$ so that the condition $a_n x_n\to0\iff\sum_n |x_n|$ converges becomes true? Maybe such a sequence doesn't exist?

Comment: @s.harp No, i don't know of such a sequence and don't think such a sequence exists. It's been a while but in my analysis class I learned that there is no series which converges slower than any other sequence, which is kind of what you are asking for. I suggest you look at the classic written by Konrad Knopp which addresses this kind of questions.